# What is the Cantonese equivalent for 你怎么样？

Tags: cantonese, greetings

Colloquial Cantonese phrases often differ significantly from Mandarin, so I would be nervous to use 你怎么样 pronounced in Cantonese.

Is there a greeting of identical (or nearly identical) meaning in Cantonese (ie, for closer acquaintances, implying "how are ya?" or "what's up?")?

Comment: This question is likely too simple for someone who has a basic understanding of Cantonese and is something you would likely already know if you were serious about learning it. This sounds like a 'how do u say hi in Chinese' type question when u are not really serious about learning"

Comment: Fair point and worthy of a down vote. I was looking for a a comment on the subtlety implied in a casual "what's up?" but I agree with your assessment.

Comment: I don't think people would often say "你怎么样？" in Mandarin. It's not very clear what you're asking about and there's a connotation of "is there something wrong with you". I guess the tone of how you say it could clarify the connotation. I think people usually add some more context like "你最近怎么样？".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Normally we use the verb "点"

> 你点啊？
> Nei5 dim2 aa3?
> leih dim a?
> English: What's up? (less formal)
>
> 你点样啊？
> Nei5 dim2 jeung5 aa3?
> leih dim yeung a?
> English: How are you doing? (more formal)
>
> 你近排点啊？
> Nei5 gan6 paai4 dim2 aa3?
> leih gan pai dim a?
> English: How have you been doing?
>
> 你呢排点啊？
> Nei5 ni1 paai4 dim2 aa3?
> leih li pai dim a?
> English: How've you been lately?

Comment: Can you translate these or note the differences between them in the tone they convey colloquially?

Comment: The first would be more casual like "How's it going?" while the second is a little more formal like "How are you doing?".  The last two are essentially the same as far as my experience goes - "How have you been?"  or "How have you been lately?".

Comment: It is curious how you use "l" in place of "n" in "nei" and "ni", @Sammi. Is that a matter of dialect or accent?

Comment: Perhaps the alternate romanization is now best removed…